# How do I fix subprocess:-exited-with-error whenever I pip install?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, abstract-syntax-tree

Whenever I try `pip install ast`, I keep receiving this error code:

```
 Downloading AST-0.0.2.tar.gz (19 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
```

```
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

I am unsure as to why this happening.

I tried:

- Installing visual code installer
- Installing C++ compiler
- Installing via Conda Prompt
- Installing via admin Terminal
- Installing via C++ VS Code
- I followed this [ast documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html)

Not sure the meaning of the error code, or why I am receiving it every time I am trying to install the ast package.

Comment: When you say "*I followed this ast documentation"* what exactly you followed? Where in the docs did you see the command `pip install ast` ?

Comment: @NickODell yes, I have been receiving this error message, even when I have tried ```pip install kivy``` I get the same error code ```subprocess-excited-with-error``. I am unsure what the error message means exactly. For future troubleshooting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [ast](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html) page you linked is part of the Python standard library. You don't need to pip install anything to use it. Just `import ast`. The [ast pip package](https://pypi.org/project/AST/) you're downloading is unrelated and last released in 2017 so it's probably just broken.